# Loopback.js - Hide password property not working

Tags: node.js, get, loopbackjs

I have a model "MyUser" inheriting from loopback's "User" model. Now, I don't want this model to expose the `password` property, so I went and read the docs:

http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Excludepropertiesfrombasemodel

and

http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Hiddenproperties

However, this doesn't seem to be working for some reason. I leave some code here:

```
{
  "name": "MyUser",
  "plural": "myusers",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "password": null,
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "cars": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Car"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": []
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

From your example it appears like you are excluding the password property instead of just hiding it.  The Hidden property would look more like this as per the example you referenced:

```
  "properties": {
    ...
    "password": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
...
   "hidden": ["password"],
...
```

Comment: If you look at the actual base User model config it is how they do it too if you're model extends User  it should work out of the box without having to override the password property